# How to create a C library with CodeBlocks?

Tags: c, dynamic, shared-libraries, static-libraries, codeblocks

How can I create a C library in CodeBlocks that can be define and used like a standard library with the `#include` command?

In fact I want to create a simple library that is Composed of several functions.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need a `.h` file for the header definitions and a `.c` containing the source code.

An example:

```
/* command.h */

#ifndef COMMAND_H
#define COMMAND_H

int func(void);

#endif /* COMMAND_H */
```

---

```
/* command.c */

#include "command.h"

int func(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
/* main.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include "command.h"

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d\n", func());
    return 0;
}
```

`ifndef` is used to prevent the file from being included more than once.

Compile it including both `.c` files in the command line:

```
gcc -o demo main.c command.c
```

Or in your case, follow [this guide](http://www.dummies.com/programming/c/how-to-link-2-source-code-files-with-c-programming/) to compile multiple files in codeblocks.